# Updating a document without deleting existing values

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have movie model which is referencing a user model by  object id. 
A user can add or remove itself from the attending list and I'm trying to implement it using mode.findOneAndUpdate. 
I read that I should add $set the existing attending user won't get deleted, but even with $set when a user adds himself all the existing users are deleted and now this user is the only one on the list.

Here's the code:

movie model

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("fhdfdca5e1b94fafadhfg1"),
    "date" : ISODate("2016-10-05T13:56:43.939Z"),
    "attending" : [ 
        ObjectId("fhdf6d0e4501f294a6dgd2")
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

here's my findandupdate:

```
   ...
.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.body.movieId}, {$set:{attending:req.body.imAttending}}, {upsert:true})
```

How do I simply add an item to my attending list?

TL;DR

use $push not $set if you don't mind repetition in your list or $addToSet for only unique values. see answer and comments below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `attending` is an array, you should use [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/):

```
.findOneAndUpdate({
  _id : req.body.dinnerId
}, {
  $push : { attending : req.body.imAttending }
}, ...)
```

Comment: Great! I'm sure that's what I was looking for since the $set didn't seem to work I suspected there's another operator for an array. Where is the list with all operators?

Comment: @S.Schenk see [this list](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/#id1) for update operators. The global list of operators starts from [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/).

Comment: I've noticed it keeps adding the same user to the list even if it was added. I tried to prevent that with unique on my attending reference list right, but that didn't work. Any clues?

Comment: @S.Schenk use [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/).

Answer (score 0):

I have had an issue like that before too. When you do find one and update use the set operator like so:

```js
modelname.findOneAndUpdate({
  email: var_email}, 
  { $set: { 
    token: var_token, 
    platform: var_platform}}, 
    { new: true }, function(err, doc) 
{
   //doc here has updated document, in case you need it. 
});
```

It looks kind of similar to what you have posted. But it should take in some parameters and set them to the current object. If this is incorrect on what you are attempting. Comment below.

Comment: Those are just parameters inside an object. I used that for devices. SO the token and platform were inside my mongodb object. For your position, it would be id, date, or attending